# haskell stack build with mongodb as dependency error

Tags: haskell, build, haskell-stack

I am trying to build a test project with stack:

I ran:

```
stack new test simple
```

then I modified Main.hs file to be:

```
module Main where

import Database.MongoDB as M

main :: IO ()
main = do
putStrLn "hello world"
```

test.cabal file to be:

```
executable test
hs-source-dirs:      src
main-is:             Main.hs
default-language:    Haskell2010
build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                    ,mongodb
```

stack.yaml file to be:

```
resolver: lts-8.5
packages:
 - '.'
extra-deps:
 - mongodb-2.1.1.1
```

when I ran "stack build", it shows following error message:

```
Warning: Some extra-deps are neither installed nor in the index:
* mongodb-2.1.1.1
Didn't see mongodb-2.1.1.1 in your package indices.
Updating and trying again.
Fetched package index.                                                                                    
The following package identifiers were not found in your indices: mongodb-2.1.1.1
```

I have checked that I have mongodb-2.1.1.1 installed with lts-8.5 snapshot.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: I think the package name is `mongoDB` not `mongodb`.

Comment: you are right, i fixed it with mongoDB.